# Is there an .m4a service provider interface for java sound?

Tags: java, audio, javasound, m4a, service-provider

I've written a simple media player that uses java sound and a bunch of different SPIs to give support for various audio formats. I haven't been able to find an SPI for .m4a yet though. I've looked at [JAAD](http://jaadec.sourceforge.net/index.php) but it seems to only have an SPI for AAC, not M4A.

Is there one out there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after doing more research, it look like JAAD should in theory work for .m4a and .mp4 containers if the audio inside is AAC. For me, It's going as far as getting the dataline, but then it's not actually reading bytes from the decoded stream. I posted this as a question here: [Java sound not playing m4a files through JAAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10369221/javasound-not-playing-m4a-files-through-jaad-an-spi)